# High voltage drop over output diode sepic converter

Tags: diodes, dc-dc-converter, sepic

I made a SEPIC converter please see the wiki for the scematic:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter

Observation:
The output is 12V 2A max. When I use a scope I see the diode is conducting for about 2/3 of the time when there is a 20V input voltage.

I reason:
the current trough the diode, when the diode is conducting, would be about 2A/(2/3) this is about 3A.I did try different kind of Schottky diodes like the STPS15L60C. When I take a look at the data-sheet they specify a voltage drop of 0.62V for 7.5A for one diode (there are 2 diodes in the package I use them both parallel).

I measure:
(1) a voltage of 1V across the diode when Voltage in is 20V (diode conducts 2/3 of the time and,
(2) a voltage of 1.2V across the diode when the input voltage is 8V (diode conducts 1/3 of the time).

According to my reasoning, this diode voltage drop seems way too much. I want to get rid of this problem as the diode is getting too hot. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my reasoning?

Regards.

Comment: How did you measure these voltages? Please show a picture of your probe method.

Comment: Thank you Andy, I did use 2 probes of the scope. I used the cursor to calculate the difference. One probe was situated at the anode the other at the cathode. setting was 1 volt a div. Probe setting was 10x same setting as  the scope. When I am back at the scope I can make a picture.

Comment: Did you use short spring earth terminals to minimize the induced emf you normally get on scope probes using the earth wire and croc clip?

Comment: You might be able to use a Schottky diode for the lower forward voltage, but they also have higher reverse leakage. Another option could be to use an active switch rather than a diode. A power MOSFET's \$R_{ds,on}\$ would result in a much smaller voltage drop than a diode. Not sure how the body diode might play into that though; I've not dealt with sepics before so it might cause a problem.